# Может ли быть вирус\бекдор на уровне процессора\сетевой карты и т.п.?

Tags: безопасность, железо, процессор

Вопрос наверное бредовый, но всё же интересно.

Условно все процессоры в мире выпускают буквально пару фирм, я думаю тоже самое грубо можно сказать про многое железо.

Допустим что этот производитель решил пересылать мою инфу еще себе на сервер ну или еще какое злонамеренное действие. Начинает все такие пакеты с определенного кода чтобы когда мы  пытаемся прослушать весь трафик чтобы эти пакеты не показывались. Формально мы это проверить никак не можем и можем только доверять той абстракции которую нам дал производитель?

Вопрос может быть не совсем корректно сформулирован или пример подобран не удачно, но всё же может ли быть что-то подобное и\или почему можно быть уверенным что такого нет?

Comment: я просто оставлю это здесь https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_backdoor А вообще - тема довольно старая, и действительно, опасения о то, что в железе есть закладки - существуют

Comment: и еще вот это - красивая статья: https://habr.com/ru/news/t/471398/

Comment: Может ли быть бэкдор в современном чипсете, имеющем целую самостоятельную неотключаемую подсистему с отдельным процессором, недокументированной, обфусцированной прошивкой, подсистему, которая работает даже при отключённом питании компьютера и через которую проходит каждый пакет ethernet-трафика? [Конечно же нет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Management_Engine).